# Python Relative Import Error appears only on server

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'm trying to start a Flask server on both my local Ubuntu machine and a remote Ubuntu server, using the same commands in the terminal for both.

```
virtual venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install flask flask_cors gunicorn #... and more
FLASK_DEBUG=1 FLASK_APP=server flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

There's no problem running the `flask run` command on my local dev machine.

However on the remote server, `flask run` is throwing an error

```
...
  File "/root/foo/src/server.py", line 31, in create_app
    from .bar import bar_blueprint
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Why does this error happens only on the remote server?

**Local machine:**

- Ubuntu 22.04.2
- Python 3.10.6

  ```
  (venv) gv@dev:~/foo/src$ python
  Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
  information.
  ```

**Remote server:**

- Ubuntu 22.10
- Python 3.10.7

  ```
  (venv) root@server:~/foo/src# python
  Python 3.10.7 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:47:39) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
  information.
  ```

Comment: `"/root/foo/src/server.py"` is pretty problematic itself when running on a server, given that it's in `root`. But, that aside, you could well be running a different version of `python` to launch the service

Comment: IOW I don't exactly believe your `Python` specs in how the service is launched. My first suspicion is that it's a different interpreter than what you _think_ is being used to launch your script

Comment: Or, you made a package of your project and forgot to install _that_ on the remote server

Comment: @roganjosh Thats a good possibility, how do I get which python interpreter is being used to launch the script?

Comment: I did not make a package of my project, but thats a good probe

Comment: The first can be evaluated easy enough. As long as you're not using any `sudo` privileges, then all you need is a terminal in the project root, `source venv/bin/activate` and then `python` to enter the interpreter to see what that is

Comment: @roganjosh Updated the question with the output of running `python` to show the interpreter version

Comment: @roganjosh Oh I was missing `~/foo/src/__init__.py` on the server (untracked by git), which is present on the local dev system. Added it to the server and it work snow. Sorry for misleading you, and thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Glad it's solved